# TextInputLayout changing color programmatically

Tags: android, styles, themes, android-textinputlayout

I would like to change the color style for the text input layout programmatically. The color is changing any moment so I need to set the color of the underline and hint text with the color I get from my server.

I could change the hint text color with the following code from another answer, but I can not change the underline color:

```
public static void setInputTextLayoutColor(TextInputLayout textInputLayout, @ColorInt int color) {
        try {
            Field fDefaultTextColor = TextInputLayout.class.getDeclaredField("mDefaultTextColor");
            fDefaultTextColor.setAccessible(true);
            fDefaultTextColor.set(textInputLayout, new ColorStateList(new int[][]{{0}}, new int[]{ color }));

            Field fFocusedTextColor = TextInputLayout.class.getDeclaredField("mFocusedTextColor");
            fFocusedTextColor.setAccessible(true);
            fFocusedTextColor.set(textInputLayout, new ColorStateList(new int[][]{{0}}, new int[]{ color }));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
textInputLAyout.getEditText().getBackground().mutate().setColorFilter(your_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Comment: Thank you but with that I get a null reference error in textInputLayout. getBackground()

Comment: You can change the underline color when edit text not in focus  with the updated answer. But if you focus color gets changed to accent. Best way to handle this is to write custom EditText and use that with in TextInputLayout

Comment: Thank you for your time, I will try to create my custom edittext